# Send Push Notification In Xamarin Forms Without Firebase

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, push-notification, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am working in banking sector and we have different portals for managing employee information, performance etc. I want to send push notification in mobile app from our asp.net web service when a new event (e.g. a Line Manager has to approve any pending request) occurs. How can I send notification to mobile app from our servers(where the web service has been deployed)? We don't have rights to place employee data on cloud servers or cloud databases.

Comment: How about sending a stupid "raw" notification that just notifies the App to fetch latest status from your backend, and then present a local notification, still using Firebase. This way you dont send any sensitive information to Firebase

Comment: @Cheesebaron How would I get information about notification in mobile app when my mobile app is not being used by user(app is closed or in background etc.)?. I'd appreciate it if you could guide me on the steps required to achieve this. Thanks!

Comment: That’s the point of push notifications- to be able to get a notification even if app is not in use. Please research the topic thoroughly. StackOverflow is not a place to get general guidance. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully this is your request:

> We don't have rights to place employee data on cloud servers or cloud
> databases.

And not this:

> Send Push Notification In Xamarin Forms Without Firebase

As they are entirely different. If you want to send data to Android devices you need to use Firebase for that just like you need to use Apple's servers for iOS devices. However you don't need to have any database or store data on them.

You can use PushSharp nuget if you want to minimize 3rd party server usage or some other similar solution.

Just for the record using Firebase (or other services like Azure) to send push notifications doesn't require you to place employee data on cloud servers either. Firebase and other solutions contain range of services that can be used independently and it seems that you consider them as all or nothing solution.